# Replace fields of arrays

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change the mail in my account, I want that in all collections where `SendTO =` current mail the value changed to new mail (`userEmail`)

I can get the collections I need, but how can I replace my old mail (`SendTo` field) with a new one?

```
// data.email new email
// userEmail currently email
await user.updateEmail(data.email);

await firestore.collection("Mission")
  .where("SendTo", "==", userEmail)
  .get()
  .then(snap => {
    let datas = snap.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    datas.map(p => firestore.collection("Mission").doc(p.idOwner).update({
      SendTo: data.email
    }))
  });

await firebase.auth().signOut();
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i need to replace old SendTo to new SendTo in each array.My code not working.

Comment: That's correct, because you're not updating the array. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46757614, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189143 and others from this: https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+javascript+update+element+in+array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Cloud Firestore, you can't update or replace an existing element in the array. In order to achieve the update operation, you have to first remove the old element by using the `arrayRemove()`. And after, use the `arrayUnion()` operation which will add the element you wanted to put as updated.

Here is the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) for the code.