# Is it possible to update specify array on firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Array like this:

[image]

I need to add another id to **group_name = Group 2** (add a new id to devices).

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible with firestore as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189143/4465386). I would suggest to make the outer array an object and then it would be possible to do somthing like this:

```
firestore.instance.
    .collection('friendships')
    .document(caller.data["uid"])
    .updateData({
         "groups.groupId": {
              FieldValue.arrayUnion({
              friendDisplayName: snapshot.data["friendDisplayName"],
              friendUid: snapshot.ref
         })
});
```

Comment: I need to add group_name equal Group 2. You can get idea from image(I attached)

Comment: @BloodLoss sorry for misunderstanding your question. I updated my answer.