# Is it possible to update the value of an array item inside another array in a firebase collection document

Tags: database, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering how I can update an item in a multidimensional array in Firebase.

It would go Collection -> Document -> Field -> Array -> Array -> Field

See my attached screen shot.

I need to update the accountBodyContent

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Update single item in an array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187985/firestore-update-single-item-in-an-array-field)

Comment: You won't be able to *modify* an element within your nested array but you can try **arrayUnion** and **arrayRemove** methods that are mentioned in the thread that I linked, in order to *replace* it.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that I would have to rewrite the whole document which could be costly so I am restructuring my document.

Comment: @DenisT. make this an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to *modify* an element within your nested array but you can use **arrayUnion** and **arrayRemove** methods to *replace* it.

[Firestore Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

Comment: Do you mind looking at another issue of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065378/download-json-file-from-firebase-storage