# Download json file from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-storage

Let me restate my question. I have a vue.js app that uploads a json file to a bucket in my firebase storage. I need to download the file to use in my app but when I try to download a json file from firebase storage I get a "Uncaught (in promise) undefined" error.

What I would like to do is download the file back into an object to use in my app

Here is my code to download and read the file:

```
const storage = firebase.storage()
const storageRef = storage.ref()
const objectRef = storageRef.child('BUCKET/FILE_NAME.json')
objectRef.download(function (err, contents) {
    if (!err) {
        var jsObject = JSON.parse(contents.toString('utf8'))
        console.log('jsObject ', jsObject)
    }
})
```

UPDATE: Here is my entire code. I check the DB for an active course. If found, I want to grab that course from storage and built out my object from its contents.

```
getActiveCourse({ dispatch }, { cid, user }) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        let userActiveCourse = []
        let archivedUserCourses = []
        let currentCourseRef = db.collection('currentcourses')
        currentCourseRef = currentCourseRef.where('cid', '==', cid)
        currentCourseRef = currentCourseRef.where('user', '==', user.uid)
        currentCourseRef.get().then(snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.empty) {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    let course = doc.data()
                    course.id = doc.id
                    if (course.status == 'active') {

                        // WE FOUND AN ACTIVE COURSE. NOW LETS DOWNLOAD IT AND READ IT INTO AN ARRAY
                        const storage = firebase.storage()
                        const storageRef = storage.ref()
                        const objectRef = storageRef.child('BUCKET/FILE_NAME.json')
                        objectRef.download(function (err, contents) {
                                 if (!err) {
                                     var jsObject = JSON.parse(contents.toString('utf8'))
                                 }
                             })
                        userActiveCourse.push(course.course)
                    } else {
                        archivedUserCourses.push(course.course)
                    }
                })
            }

        }).then(() => {
            dispatch('addUserActiveCourse', userActiveCourse)
            dispatch('addArchivedUserCourses', archivedUserCourses)

            res()
        }).catch(() => rej())
    })
},
```

Comment: If you catch the uncaught error and log it, does it show anything about what actually went wrong?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried and it never gets to it

Comment: You're throwing the cause of the error away here: `.catch(() => rej())`. That should be `.catch((err) => rej(err))`.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen now I see that objectRef.download is not a function. any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url?

Comment: Yes I looked into that, however, that is for reading an image not parsing a json file. Am I missing something? :)

Comment: It's first and foremost for downloading a file. It shows the APIs you need: `getDownloadUrl` and `fetch` (or something similar for that last one).

Comment: It seems that you are using a download method that does not exist. Storage reference does not have such methods, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the solution for anyone else needing help with this type of issue.

```
const storage = firebase.storage()
const storageRef = storage.ref()
const objectRef = storageRef.child(course.storageRef)
objectRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        let activeCourse = response.data
        userActiveCourse.push(activeCourse)
    })
})
```

Comment: I want to thank you so much for your solution. I've been pulling my hair out with the poor firebase docs and this has helped me complete what I thought should be a simple bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to start a Firebase project

Open the Firebase console.
Click “CREATE NEW PROJECT”.

1. The “Create a project” window opens.
2. The start screen of the Firebase console opens.
3. The “Enter app details” screen opens.
4. Continue the configuration by following the on-screen instruction.
5. Check the server key after the project is created.
6. Down the server key and store it on your local drive for now.

Now that we have installed dependencies and created a Firebase project, just create an index.js file and paste the below code. Don’t worry, we will go over the code in detail, to understand what is happening.

Comment: Maybe I did not write my question properly. I do not need info on creating a project in firebase. I am uploading json files to storage and then I need to red that file.