# React Native using firestore updating array

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a mobile chat application to learn how to use cloud services and have been having some difficulty updating my array of maps without overwriting the array. I have tried multiple different ways but I can only either get it so it overwrites the whole array, or does nothing. I was trying to follow the documentation from firebase for NodeJS to append to the array but cannot get it to work. Any tips on what I am doing wrong? (in my code: db = firebase.firestore();)

```
sendMessage = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let date = new Date();

        const res2 = await db.collection('indivualChats').doc(this.state.chatID).update({
            messages: db.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                mid: res.id,
                msg: this.state.message,
                timeSent: date.getDate() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear(),
                uid: auth.currentUser.uid})
            });

        this.setState({
            message: '',
        })
};
```

[cloud data layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPM6n.png)

Answer (score 0):

From [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189143/8753991) you can't direct update of a specific index of array. The alternative way is to read the entire document, modify the data in memory and update the field back into the document or based on the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) you can use `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()` to add and remove elements.

My example:

**Data structure**:

[image]

**Codes in nodejs**:

```
async function transaction(db) {
    const ref = db.collection('users').doc('john');
    try {
    await db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
        const doc = await t.get(ref)
        const newmessage = 'hello world!';
        t.update(ref, {
            "message": admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                text: newmessage
            })
        });
        t.update(ref, {
            'message': admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({
                    text:doc.data().message[0].text
            })
        })
    });

        console.log('Transaction success!');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Transaction failure:', e);
    }
}
transaction(db);
```