# How to add data on nested array in Firestore with react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I would like to ask if is it possible to add data in a nested array.The result i want is this [image]

But i get this when i add a new rating with the code i use

[image]

```
async function getAll(){
    const userEmail= firebase.firestore().collection('users')
    const snapshot=await userEmail.where('email','==',index.email).get()
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }  
    
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      userEmail.doc(doc.id).set({userRatings2:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({parking:[markerName]})},{merge:true})
      userEmail.doc(doc.id).set({userRatings2:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({rating:[currentRating]})},{merge:true})

     
      
     console.log(userEmail.doc(doc.id));
    });
  }
  getAll()
```

Comment: can you add your updated code in this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in Firebase `Firestore` you can't even change a simple Array value at a specific `index`. That means also that you can't save nested array values. You can read more about it on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189143/5519300).

The only way to do it is to download the whole Array make your modifications and save the whole array again to the databse. There is not much context of your app so I can't tell if that is a good solution for you. It depends how much data you have in the array.

Comment: Yes i've tried this way and it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it by using forEach function to an array of image path

```
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState([]);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

  const UploadImage = () => {
    setUploading(true);
    imageUri.forEach(async (image, index) => {
      // setTransferred(0);

      const pathToFile = image;
      let filename = pathToFile.substring(pathToFile.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
      const extension = filename.split('.').pop();
      const name = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
      filename = name + Date.now() + '.' + extension;

      const reference = storage().ref().child(`/userprofile/${filename}`);
      // path to existing file on filesystem

      // uploads file
      const task = reference.putFile(pathToFile);
      try {
        await task;

        const url = await reference.getDownloadURL();
        downloadableURI.push(url);
        if (index == imageUri.length - 1) {
          setUploading(false);
          Alert.alert(
            'Image uploaded!',
            'Your image has been uploaded to the Firebase Cloud Storage Successfully!',
          );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
  };
```

whenever the function is called, then the array of images is uploaded to firebase storage,